# How to check if input contains one of array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, input

I have an input like this:

```
<input name='postImg' type='text'><?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['postImg'];}?></input>
```

I would like PHP to check if the input text contains:
.png or .jpeg or .gif etc.
To make sure its a image. But it has to be input name (so no upload).

How can I do this best?

Comment: note that matching filenames isn't a reliable way of checking "is this an image"? `ren nastyvirus.exe cutekittens.jpg`, for one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression. This will check that the extension is correct; matching (.png, .jpeg, .jpg, .gif) the end of the string

```
if( preg_match("/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/", $_POST['postImg']) ) {
   //Yep.
}
```

Example: https://eval.in/208018

#### Edit

```
if( strlen($postImg) > 0 AND preg_match("/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/", $postImg) == FALSE) {
   $error[] = 'Wrong image format.';
}
```

Comment: For some reason it isnt working. My other statements aren't working anymore.
Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/hF6p9fVA

Comment: Try something like: http://pastebin.com/SiEeGU3U (You are also trying to insert into the database even if there were errors. I've switched the logic on that for you, too)

Comment: Ok, that's working. Thanks.

But could you add something that it is also possible to leave postImg empty?

Comment: Sure, add an `OR` clause within the `if` logic. `if( empty($_POST['postImg']) OR ...`

Comment: `if( empty($postImg) OR preg_match("/\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$/", $postImg) == FALSE) {}` If the string is blank OR the regular expression brings no matches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63352/discussion-between-mrdikke-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(strpos($_POST['postImg'], '.png') || strpos($_POST['postImg'], '.jpeg') || strpos($_POST['postImg'], '.gif')) {
    echo 'It exists';
}
```

Comment: This will allow `input.png.exe`, which isn't an image. You'd need to match the extension, not the contents of the string.